# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 14 path $.userData

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I hv a program with login activity. i'm using retrofit 2 to fetch data. I'm using post method. When i post the username and password, it should retrieve data user. But I'm getting this error. It confused me, I don't know where is the mistakes. Please help me to find the error and please tell me how to fix it. Thank you.

Json

```
{
 "userData": [
    {
      "id_user": "3",
      "name": null,
      "email": "nickyapriliani11@gmail.com",
      "phone_number": "08564327587",
      "address": null,
      "id_image": null,
      "occupation": null,
      "gender": null,
      "blood_type": null,
      "birthday": null,
      "username": "nicky11",
      "password": "450089f47156609e17ea51992a2d49fbf6f608648ee90fe7240d795fb84bde43",
      "poin": "0",
      "longitude": null,
      "latitude": null,
      "create_at": "2017-03-24 19:22:56",
      "update_at": "2017-03-24 19:22:56",
      "flag": "1"
    }
  ],
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Login Succeed"
}
```

UserResponse

```
   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserResponse extends ApiBaseResponse implements Serializable {
    private List<UserModel> userData;


    public List<UserModel> getUserData() {
        return userData;
    }

    public void setUserData(List<UserModel> userData) {
        this.userData = userData;
    }
}
```

UserModel.Java

```
   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UserModel {

    private String  id_user,name,email,phone_number,address,photo_profile,occupation,
            gender,blood_type,birthday,username,password,poin,longitude,latitude;
    public String getId_user() {
        return id_user;
    }

    public void setId_user(String id_user) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
    }

    public String getPoin() {
        return poin;
    }

    public void setPoin(String poin) {
        this.poin = poin;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id_user;
    }

    public void setId(String id_user) {
        this.id_user = id_user;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone_number() {
        return phone_number;
    }

    public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
        this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoto_profile() {
        return photo_profile;
    }

    public void setPhoto_profile(String photo_profile) {
        this.photo_profile = photo_profile;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getBlood_type() {
        return blood_type;
    }

    public void setBlood_type(String blood_type) {
        this.blood_type = blood_type;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.Java

```
private void Login()
{
    final ProgressDialog mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.show();

    String user=mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String pass=decryptPass(mPasswordView.getText().toString());

    apiData api= ApiClient.getClient().create(apiData.class);
    Call<UserResponse> call= api.Login(user,pass);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful())
            {
                UserResponse result=response.body();
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "response = " + new Gson().toJson(result));
                if(result !=null)
                {
                    session.createLoginSession(result.getUserData().get(0));
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("Error Login: ",t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

The error is

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 14 path $.userData

Comment: One of the fields in your GSON is a string, and not a list

Comment: After getting user object response from server where you parsing ??

Comment: can u find it in the above code? Or canu tell me how can i find it? @cricket_007

Comment: it should be parse to here UserResponse result=response.body(); @Srihari

Comment: does your `response.body()` is equals to above json you provide ?

Comment: actually when i debug my apps, the response is failure.But the response.body should provide my json above @Srihari

Comment: then possible some minor issue inside that api debug `api.Login(user,pass)` inside this method

Comment: how can i find what's the problem? @Srihari

Comment: Debug inside that method `api.Login(user,pass)` check where exactly exception